# gnome-terminal broke after adding command to initialize

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I just broke my gnome-terminal.

At the options I tried to force my terminal to open with 256 colors adding the command:

`export TERM=xterm-256color`

but now my terminal open and exits immediately.

How can I remove this command?

Comment: when you say open and exit you mean it opens up and then closes by itself?

Comment: yeap, that's right. And I don't have any config at ~/.gconf/apps/

Comment: Hey, I fixed! Using xterm! But it wasn't a solution, but it's fixed now! :|

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you set this command up, did you just run it in the terminal?

Comment: Profiles > Profile Preferences > Command > Custom command: Here I made the mess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `gnome-terminal -x sh` or `gnome-terminal -e bash` (from `xterm` or directly as command by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and you will get `gnome-terminal` with `sh/bash`.

Then after Go to: Profiles > Profile Preferences > Command > Custom command (where you've set `export TERM=xterm-256color`) and make correction